# docker image 'swift:5.5.2-xenial' can not build

Tags: swift, docker, dockerfile

[the issue](https://github.com/apple/swift-docker/issues/263)

The image was building fine before, but now for some reason it won't build.
I created my own Dockerfile to reference this image:

```
FROM swift:5.5.2-xenial

CMD ["sh"]
```

When I build the image using this Dockerfile, I encounter the same error when building either locally or in another image:

```
tar: dev/agpgart: cannot mknod: operation not permitted
...
```

What should i do? Please do me a favor~

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately this problem has been solved.

I deleted the original build of the docker image and rebuilt it locally.

It inexplicably worked.